# Pass parameter(s) to the XSLT mode

Tags: xslt-3.0

When applying

```xml
<apply-templates  mode="extract.controlEvents" select="$extractedEvents">
     <with-param name="pMultiRestMeasures" select="$multiRestMeasures"/>
   </apply-templates>
```

I expected `$pMultiRestMeasures` to be availble in the matched template:

```xml
<template match="measure[.//mRest]" mode="extract.controlEvents">
        <param name="pMultiRestMeasures"/>
    
        <choose>
          <when test="$pMultiRestMeasures">
         ...
          </when>
        </choose>
    
      </template>
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case. I also tried using `@tunnel`.

I need to perform calculations before the mode is called. Numerous other templates are invoked using this mode, but they do not require this parameter. "on-no-match", the identity transform is invoked. Note: the mode(s) are not explicitly declared using `xsl:mode`.

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the error or wrong result you get, also explaining whether you get an error or just not the result you want.

Comment: It also in general helps understanding and debugging code if you use `as` attributes with type annotations, so far it is not clear what kind of values you want to pass on, an empty string, a boolean false and perhaps others could easily fail the `<when test="$pMultiRestMeasures">` check.

Comment: Also the statement '"on-no-match", the identity transform is invoked. Note: the mode(s) are not explicitly declared using `xsl:mode`' sounds a bit confusing as long as you don't show exactly how you set up the identity transformation for your modes or at least that particular mode `extract.controlEvents`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cstylesheet%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%20version%3D%223.0%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%20xmlns%3Aarray%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Farray%22%20xmlns%3Adme%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mozarteum.at%2Fns%2Fdme%22%20xmlns%3Afunctx%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.functx.com%22%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%20xmlns%3Amei%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.music-encoding.org%2Fns%2Fmei%22%20xmlns%3Axd%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oxygenxml.com%2Fns%2Fdoc%2Fxsl%22%20xmlns%3Axi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXInclude%22%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%20xpath-default-namespace%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.music-encoding.org%2Fns%2Fmei%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Coutput%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20method%3D%22xml%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cstrip-space%20elements%3D%22*%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%20match%3D%22node%28%29%20%7C%20%40*%22%20mode%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Capply-templates%20mode%3D%22%23current%22%20select%3D%22node%28%29%20%7C%20%40*%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fcopy%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxd%3Adoc%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxd%3Adesc%3EMain%20template.%3C%2Fxd%3Adesc%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxd%3Adoc%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22main%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cvariable%20name%3D%22extractedEvents%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Capply-templates%20mode%3D%22extract.events%22%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fvariable%3E%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cvariable%20as%3D%22element%28%29%22%20name%3D%22multiRestMeasures%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccall-template%20name%3D%22calculate.multirest.measures%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cwith-param%20as%3D%22document-node%28%29%22%20name%3D%22pDocNode%22%20select%3D%22%24extractedEvents%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fcall-template%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fvariable%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cvariable%20name%3D%22extractedControlEvents%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Capply-templates%20mode%3D%22extract.controlEvents%22%20select%3D%22%24extractedEvents%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cwith-param%20as%3D%22element%28%29%22%20name%3D%22pMultiRestMeasures%22%20select%3D%22%24multiRestMeasures%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fapply-templates%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fvariable%3E%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccopy-of%20select%3D%22%24extractedControlEvents%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%20name%3D%22calculate.multirest.measures%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cparam%20as%3D%22document-node%28%29%22%20name%3D%22pDocNode%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cconfig%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mozarteum.at%2Fns%2Fdme%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3ClayersToDelete%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24pDocNode%2Flayer%5BmRest%5D%2F%40xml%3Aid%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FlayersToDelete%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fconfig%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%20match%3D%22staff%5B.%2F%2FmRest%5D%22%20mode%3D%22extract.controlEvents%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cparam%20as%3D%22element%28%29%22%20name%3D%22pMultiRestMeasures%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cchoose%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cwhen%20test%3D%22%24pMultiRestMeasures%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22test%22%20select%3D%22%27passed%27%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Capply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%20except%20%40n%2C%20node%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fcopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fwhen%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cotherwise%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22test%22%20select%3D%22%27not%20passed%27%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Capply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%20except%20%40n%2C%20node%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fcopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fotherwise%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fchoose%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fstylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Cstaff%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.music-encoding.org%2Fns%2Fmei%22%20xml%3Aid%3D%22staff_9384%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Clayer%20xml%3Aid%3D%22layer_9390%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CmRest%20xml%3Aid%3D%22mRest_9396%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Flayer%3E%0A%3C%2Fstaff%3E%0A&input-type=XML) is the XSLT Fiddle with an MRE.

But I solved it for me by adding `@tunnel`. Don't know why it did not work the first time.